# Angular Service, no return when API is used

Tags: angular, service

I am trying Angular service for the first time, and I am having trouble while I use the API in the service. When I call the regular method, I get a return value, but when I call the method that uses API, I don't get any return value.

**Here's my app.component.ts file.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core;
enter code hereimport { DataService } from './data.service;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  _artists: Array<any>
  _produceArray: Array<any>
  title = 'APIAssignmentPartBandCVersion2';
 
  constructor(private list: DataService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this._artists = this.list.getList()
      this._produceArray = this.list.getProduce()
      console.log(this._produceArray, "hellohello")
      console.log(this._artists, "artistArray")
    }
}
```

**Here's my data.service file.**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
const BASE_URL = 'https://localhost:44308/api/Store/';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

_producesArray: Array<any>;
_suppliersArray: Array<any>;
_producesupplierArray: Array<any>;
_errorMessage: String = "";

getList(){
    return[
      {'grade':1, 'name':'Davido', 'country':'Nigeria'},
      {'grade':2, 'name':'Burna Boy', 'country':'Nigeria'},
      {'grade':3, 'name':'Diamondz Platinum', 'country':'Tanzania'},
      {'grade':4, 'name':'Sarkodie', 'country':'Ghana'},
      {'grade':5, 'name':'Mr. Eazi', 'country':'Nigeria'}
    ];
  }

getProduce(){
  this.http.get<any>(BASE_URL + "produce/").subscribe(data => {
    this._producesArray = data;
    this._errorMessage = data["errorMessage"]; 
    console.log(data)
},
error =>{
    this._errorMessage = JSON.stringify(error);
})
return this._producesArray
}
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that - you call the API which is asynchronic action which means is moving on to the next line of code while this request is execute...
so you return `_producesArray` before it's really filled with data.
what do you need to do is simply return the observable like this:

```
 return this.http.get<any>(BASE_URL + "produce/")
```

and make the `subscribe` inside the component

```
this.list.getProduce().subscribe(...)
```

good luck :)